# How to install and launch mahout for spark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, ubuntu-14.04, mahout, bigdata

I am interested in learning machine learning algorithms for big data, and for that purpose I want to learn how to code in Mahout for Spark. Now I have posted my original question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553439/how-to-start-mahout-spark-shell), but nobody answered, so I am modifying my question now.

If anyone knows detailed procedures how to install **LATEST** Spark in Ubuntu 14.04 and how to integrate **MAHOUT** for it, I will be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Mahout uses:

- [Spark 1.6.2](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/pom.xml#L124)
- [Scala 2.10.4](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/pom.xml#L123)

You can try [to build](https://mahout.apache.org/developers/buildingmahout.html) your own version with Spark 2.0 and Scala version of choice but there is no guarantee it will work correctly.

Exception you report in your other version is a result of Scala version mismatch.

Comment: Feel free to watch [MAHOUT-1889](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1889) and up vote if you would like to see this integration.